# Simple accessible microcontroller for learning low level digital logic

Tags: digital-logic

Sorry if this isn't the right place for this question- if so, please correct/redirect.

I have a technical background, but as for electrical engineering and programming, I'm really just a hobbyist.

I'd like to identify a microcontroller or IC that I can use for learning digital logic at the lowest level- is this called 'machine language'?

Ideally, it would be a popular device with an active user base/community, and lots of simple projects.

Most importantly, though, is that I want to be able to actually write code at the lowest level, and build abstraction on top of that, all for the purpose of hands-on learning.

recommendations for educational resources like online courses and the like would also be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Digital logic is independent of any coding. It is the lowest form of digital electronics possible. http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/index.php?cPath=3500&osCsid=itk9uh5b4eu3foksdlivfod8j1

Comment: Thanks, I understand, so what I'm looking for is an electronics platform that's one level up from that where I can interface at a transistor level and get a hands on feel for building up useful code from the most basic level. Essentially, I want to remove the abstractions of interfacing with code that someone else has written.

Comment: Sounds like you want to learn Assembly language? A Microchip PIC might be a good start.

Comment: Just one level up from transistor is Hardware Description Language. Then, if, from there, you implement a CPU, you can start talking about "machine language". But honestly, the way you wrote your post makes me sceptical. Maybe just get an Arduino, you'll learn a lot with that already, and there is a huge community around it.

Comment: Most MCU's will let you hand craft opcodes or write in an assembly language directly translated to them; the possible exceptions would be highly proprietary or odd architectures restricted to a vendor toolchain, or machines which can only run interpreted code (though you could argue virtual machines are still machines).  Generally this is too broad for a question here; personally, though everything has quirks an ARM Cortex part is practically current, multi-source, and has a fairly clean and self-consistent programming model. But don't rule out the PC you are sitting at as a target either.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work directly on the hardware without using other peoples code libraries then assembly language is probably a good option.  Each assembly instruction will translate directly into an executable word of machine code.

Coding machine language directly is usually very tedious and not done my most people.

The choice of a microcontroller involves many factors.

1)  How complex is the CPU core and instruction set

If you are just starting out you probably don't want to pick an ARM, x86, Power-PC, or MIPS type microcontroller.  The instruction sets are usually quite complicated.

The Atmel AVR series of microcontrollers is easy to learn.  Specifically the AT-Tiny and AT-Mega types.  They have 16 or 32 8-bit registers.  They understand 50-ish instructions.  They support multiple interrupt vectors.
http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/

The PIC16 and PIC18 series of 8-bit microcontrollers are very simple.  They have only one working register.  Some of the PIC16s have as few as 30 instructions.  The PIC type microcontrollers access memory using a bank select register field, which adds some complexity when writing programs.  They support one high priority and one low priority interrupt vector.  Some of the PIC-16 MCUs are so stripped down that they don't have built in debugger support.  Use of the debugger makes it much easier to write programs so keep that in mind.  The PIC-18 MCUs do have debuggers support on every chip I have used so far.

http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/8-bit

8051 based CPUs are simple, made by many different vendors, and have been around for decades.  The 8051 CPU is often embedded inside of other chips when a vendor wants to add programmability.

2)  The software development tools.  You don't want to pick something with tools that cost a fortune.

The tools for the AVR series microcontrollers is called Atmel Studio, and it is free.

http://www.atmel.com/tools/atmelstudio.aspx?tab=overview

Microchip corporation offers MPLAB-X for free for developing with PIC series MCUs.

http://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide

3)  The available development kits.

The JTAG ICE3 programmer from Atmel costs around $53 and programs most of their AVR microcontrollers.

http://www.atmel.com/tools/jtagice3.aspx

Microchip corporation offers development kits such as the curiosity development board (with integrated programmer) for as little as $32.

http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM164136

The general purpose Microchip programmer MPLAB-ICD3 costs around $199.

http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/Listing.aspx?CatID=bc05135f-75a9-4aa6-a6c5-82bdc9903a4c&LeftNavId=bc05135f-75a9-4aa6-a6c5-82bdc9903a4c

4)  The user community.  Both the Atmel and Microchip microcontrollers have good user forums.

http://www.avrfreaks.net/

http://www.microchip.com/forums/

Comment: Thank you very much user96037- that's a great overview of options that sound really accessible.

Comment: AVRs have 32 (not 16) registers... :)

Comment: @JimmyB The low end AT-Tiny AVRs only have 16 registers.  The AT-Mega AVRs have 32.  http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8127-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny4-ATtiny5-ATtiny9-ATtiny10_Datasheet-Summary.pdf

Comment: This is ultimately fairly misleading, both in mistaking optional complexity for necessary, and as a result of being so incomplete in what it says (or doesn't say) about choices it recommends against in flawed conclusions that likely follow from that incompleteness.  It's a good example of why we don't allow questions like this here.

Comment: You're right; I stand corrected.